# Someone can explain this Whooshes tutorial?

Tags: whooshes, whoosh

I found this: http://designingsound.org/2010/02/charles-deenen-special-100-whooshes-in-2-minutes/
and it seems really awesome for creating great whooshes, but I can't understand the procedure. Everything is clear till the creation of submixes where to route similar kind of sounds, but then I'm lost:D
Is there someone very patient that can describe all steps? :)

Comment: I think it's clearly explained, if you just know the standard terms(?). Might help googling about those, if you have trouble understanding e.g. side-chaining or submixes.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I found this confusing as well when I first tried it, and even still I'm not sure if I'm getting it properly.  Let me see if I can clarify by breaking it down into a few extra steps - and perhaps someone who really knows what they're talking about can correct my errors.

"Step One"

1. Create 10 audio tracks
2. On each track, edit in sounds with the characteristics that you want (growls, tones, distortion, etc)
3. Use the duplicate command to create 4-5 minutes of continuous sound.
4. See the video for examples

"Step Two"

1. Create 3 Aux Tracks.
2. Open your I/O, choose the Bus tab and create 3 buses (Choose New Path, make sure the Mapping To Output box is not checked) and name your buses Submix 1, Submix 2, and Submix 3.
3. Set the Input of each Aux track to a different Submix bus (ie: Submix 1 should be routed to Aux track 1, etc)
4. Add a number of plugins to the Inserts of each Aux track - Dopplers, Low-End Enhancers, etc
5. Set the output of each audio track to one of your Submix buses - try to route similar sounds to the same bus
6. When Charles mentions setting up buses with side-chain ducking, he suggests that "if Submix 1 has the more “agressive” sounds, then Submix 1 should duck down submix 2, etc".  To achieve this, open your I/O.  Create a new bus, and this time call it "Sidechain Bus".
7. Now, set the output of your first Aux track to Sidechain Bus.
8. Add a gate/compressor plugin that can be used to duck your audio to the Inserts of Aux 2, and set the Sidechain Input of the plugin to "Sidechain Bus."  Make sure the plugin is set up properly.
9. Set the output of Aux 2 and 3 to your main output.  As Charles explains, "Send the main submix signal to a aux gate, so it only opens up at the loudest point..."  So we'll set Aux 1 to go through an aux gate.  Add a new Aux track, set its Input to "Sidechain Bus" (remember we set Aux 1's output as Sidechain Bus) and its output to your Main Output.  Add a Gate Insert (C1 Gate, for example), and set its input to Sidechain Bus as well.  If you've done this properly, Aux 1 is not only used to duck the other aux tracks but it also "only opens up at the loudest point."

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. This way is much more clear indeed! I'll try tonight to set all things up and see what happens ;)

Comment: Hi @Bryce, I set all up and it doesn't sound like the "solo track example" video, but just moving faders I created a couple of nice whooshes, during 40 seconds of recording. Better than nothing for now :D
I see in his example that he achieve a "volume rise and decay" just hitting play. What I achieve is something like that but not so accurate and clear.

Comment: Hi, glad that helped.  As I said I'm still not sure if I'm getting it properly either - I did find his instructions a bit unclear.  I think your results will also depend on what plugins and settings you have and what sounds you've used.  You won't get the exact same results as him unless you've got the exact same settings, plugins, and edits.

Comment: That's also true. I'll experiment, with other sfx sources and fx plugins;)

Comment: Best of luck. I'm surprised no one else has chimed in here to correct or add to my explanation.

Comment: 2019 - I still dont get this. Step Two.9 – Why would you route you audio to an aux containig a gate, that is sidechained by the same audio signal?

Answer (score 3):

thing is, it was hard to figure out how to do this when I had it in my head and make it work without a loop-back, so I'm sorry that you didn't understand at first. Believe me it puzzled me at first as well :)  I'm glad @JohnSoundSnow was able to help you out